# printing fields is not working while running html form

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to run a simple PHP-HTML code , that prints the entered text-fields

**ex.html**

```
    <html>
<body>

<form action="exx.php" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**exx.php**

```
    <html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When i run the ex.html , and enter random text and click **submit**

The output is :

> Welcome Your email address is:

I wonder why ?

Comment: It works for me using PHP 5.1.6.  What version of PHP are you using?  Edited to add: I seem to remember that older versions of PHP cannot use $_GET directly in an echo.

Comment: how can i know what version oh PHP i have ?

Comment: Run `<?= phpinfo(); ?>` and check right on top.

Answer (score 1):

Are you seeing the results displayed in the URL?

```
www.site.com/exx.php?name=john&email=jdoe@somthing.com
```

**EDIT:**

Give this a shot.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php if($_GET){
    echo 'Welcome ' . $_GET['name'] . '</br>';
    echo 'Your eamil address is: ' . $_GET['email'];
} else {?>
<form action="" method="get">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

ALthough slightly different, I just test this and it works.

NOTE: If you are going to ever put this on a live server and or ever have users touching it, make sure you use proper sanitation. If you are building a login script, please use $_POST instead, along with sanitation, and PDO.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I run it from my hard drive

Comment: Have you tried checking isset($_GET['name']);

Not sure if it matters but I use single quotes in all mine. Give that a shot.

Comment: @jjonesdesign There is no difference between single/double quotes in this context (besides a _minuscule_ fraction of a second speed difference).

Comment: @noahu thanks for verification, I didn't think there was much difference, and both his example and mine worked fine on a live server. Just wanted the throw the idea out there for him to try.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to work for all recent versions of PHP:

```
<body>
<?php
  $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'empty';
  $email = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : 'empty';
?>
Welcome <?php echo $name ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $email ?>
```

As an added bonus, you can use only one echo:

```
<body>
<?php
  $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'empty';
  $name = isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : 'empty';
  echo "Welcome $name <br>Your email address is: $email"
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the GET variables defined in the URL, but they still aren't displaying, then $_GET must be undefined.

If you're using a version of PHP < 4.1.0, the $_GET superglobal would be undefined here. In that case, you would use $HTTP_GET_VARS instead:

**exx.php**

```
<html>
    <body>
    Welcome <?php echo $HTTP_GET_VARS["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $HTTP_GET_VARS["email"]; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

To see what version of PHP you're running, you can use the `phpinfo()` function for PHP >= 4.0, or you can use the command `php --version` at the command line in most unix-like operating systems (probably Windows too).

Answer (score 0):

Am sorry guys , turned out to be that am not running the files through `localhost`
, and instead from the hard-drive it self.

that was the problem.

Comment: You still need `isset` before you put your code into production, and to handle the case where something is not set.